# What song is playing in DBS episode 130 at 4:22? (UI Goku vs Jiren)

Tags: music, dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball

I've been searching for that **legendary guitar rift** for a while now and can't seem to find it in any OST. 
(starts at exactly 4:22 in ep 130)

I used Shazam, it kinda worked but not really. The result I got was: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03YISiMdtFE
which is the music **but it's a different version with singing**, while the version used on the show had no singing. < that's the one I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

The song is ***究極の聖戦*** (***kyūkyoku no battle*** in romaji<sup>[1]</sup> or ***Ultimate Battle*** in english). There are two versions of this song:

1. The one performed by Akira Kushida (the version Shazam found)
2. The one without vocals (the version you are looking for)

[According to Anison](http://anison.info/data/source/63924.html), the version without vocals is named ***究極の聖戦 (カラオケ)*** (where "カラオケ" means "karaoke").

I searched on YouTube that exact term and found it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P2caRnjXP0

---

<sup>1. [J-Talk translates "聖戦" as "seisen"](https://j-talk.com/khjtrhp) but many sources use "battle" instead. I have no idea which one is correct.</sup>